# Smooth modifier settings to match Subsurf

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

Is there a way to use the Smooth tool or modifier to smooth a mesh by exactly the same amount as using a subdivision surface on it would? For example, if you had a mesh, then gave one copy of it a subsurf with smooth, and another copy of it you ran a subdivide on and then used a smooth modifier, could you get them to match up?

How about if you didn't subsurf the second version? Could you get smooth settings that would have the shared vertices of the two meshes end up in the same location?

Comment: I think the two methods are unrelated, even they look similar. subsurfing is not simply an automated smooth, it's an interpolation method, and its results look smoother... But why is it important for you to know this? if you need to get a mesh identical to what subsurf would do, you can just apply the subsurf modifier.

Comment: It's not specifically important for anything, I was just curious. Sometimes it's nice to achieve the same things by different methods, especially when working with Freestyle, as it gives you more options for how to work with your geometry.